# What is gdomap and what is it used for?

Tags: 12.04

Since upgrade 12.04 LTS I noted this process because it's giving errors on startup and shutdown:

```
unable to stat gdomap
```

What is gdomap? What is it used for? Can be safely removed? How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## What Is gdomap?

[gdomap](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Tools/Reference/gdomap.html) is a daemon used by GNUstep programs. GNUstep is a framework for building applications that adheres to the OpenStep API specifications.

## Is it safe to disable/remove gdomap?

Richard Frith-Macdonald [stated](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnustep/2010-06/msg00091.html) the following in 2010:

> The gdomap deamon is completely unused for most applications!   I don't think 
>   any GNUstep applications use it in normal operation (ie if you haven't given 
>   them command-line options to tell them to communicate between different 
>   hosts/users).  The vast majority of DO connections are private to a single user 
>   on a single machine and use message ports (implemented as unix domain sockets 
>   or as message queues on mswindows) and they don't need/use a namesperver as 
>   name information is written to the local filesystem (or windows registry).

I don't know if every application using the gdomap daemon has to register a name, but I listed the registered applications and found nothing:

```
$ gdomap -N
No names currently registered with gdomap
```

I also listed to see what other applications listed gnustep as a dependency and only found gnustep-games:

```
$ sudo apt-cache rdepends gnustep
gnustep
Reverse Depends:
  gnustep-games
```

## How do I disable/remove gdomap?

So, you can temporarily turn gdomap off until the next restart:

```
$ sudo service gdomap stop
```

Or, you can stop the service and prevent it from starting on boot:

```
$ sudo service gdomap stop
$ sudo update-rc.d -f gdomap remove
# re-enable with: sudo update-rc.d gdomap defaults
```

Or, you can completely remove GNUStep:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge gnustep
# NOTE: I had to run this too:
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I removed GNUStep on my server; if I encounter any issues I'll be sure to post back.

Answer (score 2):

gdomap:

> The gdomap daemon is used by GNUstep programs to look up distributed
>   objects of processes running across the network (and between different
>   user accounts on a single machine). The deamon is NOT used for lookup
>   where two processes belonging to the same user are using a host-local
>   connection.

You can turn gdomap off.

You can disable unwanted/unused services in Ubuntu in a very easy way. Go to *System* > Administration > Services.  For more info see 
[How To Disable Unwanted Services In Ubuntu.](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-disable-unwanted-services-in-ubuntu-linux/)

Source: http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Tools/Reference/gdomap.html

Comment: I had already found this "definition" googling around, but I need some more specific explaination about what gdomap REALLY does. Ex.: what services/processes will not function if I disable it or what else depends on it.

Comment: @Mitch Like jasmines says, I still don't get what it's really for. Could you elaborate?